# FFI Gem LoadError on Ruby 2.2.0

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, compiler-errors, ffi

I wrote a Library in C++ and I want to extend it using FFI on ruby.

I did:

`gem install ffi`
and 
`gem install ffi --platform=ruby`

And that didn't work so I tried adding it to the gemfile and then `bundle install`

Doing that resolved the referencing issue I had but when I try to run this extconf.rb file:

```
require 'ffi'

module ECGInterpreterLib
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib 'Lib/TesisECGLib.so' # load library from the same folder
  attach_function :Diagnose, [:int], :uint
end
```

I get this error:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/Sam/RubymineProjects/EKGAPI/config/extconf.rb
 (LoadError)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `map'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ffi-1.9.14/lib/ffi/library.rb:100:in `ffi_lib'
    from C:/Users/Sam/RubymineProjects/EKGAPI/config/extconf.rb:6:in `<module:ECGInterpreterLib>'
    from C:/Users/Sam/RubymineProjects/EKGAPI/config/extconf.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I have read all related topics and I don't seem to find the answer

Any Ideas on how to Solve this?